# I have updated the domain.xml while Domain controller is running - wildfly

Tags: java, jboss, dns, wildfly, domaincontroller

After updating the `domain.xml`, I stopped the server using cli and tried to start.

Here is the exception I see in the logs

> [Host Controller] ^[[0m^[[33m09:47:50,511 WARN 
>   [org.jboss.as.domain.management.security] (MSC service thread 1-2)
>   WFLYDM0111: Keystore
>   /product/jboss/wildfly-14.0.0.Final/domain/configuration/application.keystore
>   not found, it will be auto generated on first use with a self signed
>   certificate for host localhost^[[0m [Host Controller]
>   ^[[33m^[[0m^[[0m09:47:50,554 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC
>   service thread 1-1) WFLYRMT0001: Listening on 0.0.0.0:9990^[[0m [Host
>   Controller] ^[[0m^[[31m09:47:50,600 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail]
>   (MSC service thread 1-8) MSC000001: Failed to start service
>   org.wildfly.management.http.extensible:
>   org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service
>   org.wildfly.management.http.extensible: java.net.BindException:
>   Address already in use /0.0.0.0:9990^[[0m [Host Controller] ^[[31m
>   at
>   org.jboss.as.server.mgmt.UndertowHttpManagementService.start(UndertowHttpManagementService.java:349)^[[0m
>   [Host Controller] ^[[31m        at
>   org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1736)^[[0m
>   [Host Controller] ^[[31m        at
>   org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1698)^[[0m
>   [Host Controller] ^[[31m        at
>   org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1556)^[[0m
>   [Host Controller] ^[[31m        at
>   org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)^[[0m
>   [Host Controller] ^[[31m        at
>   org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)^[[0m
>   [Host Controller] ^[[31m        at
>   org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)^[[0m
>   [Host Controller] ^[[31m        at
>   org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)^[[0m
>   [Host Controller] ^[[31m        at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)^[[0m [Host Controller]
>   ^[[31m^[[0m [Host Controller] ^[[31m^[[0m^[[31m09:47:50,605 ERROR
>   [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot
>   Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([^[[0m

How do I resolve this. I tried using `netstat` command to see if that port is being used, but its not been used.

Comment: What did you update in domain.xml.  Did you check port 9090 or 8080?

Comment: I changed the names of server groups in domain.xml, I checked 9990.

Comment: As an aside it's best to use CLI to make these changes rather than editing the XML directory.

Answer (score 0):

Only time I've seen an error like that is when the process didn't actually shutdown cleanly and was sitting there in a hung state. Obviously that doesn't explain why you're not seeing the port in use via netstat, but can you confirm that no other jboss or wildfly processes are still showing up in the process list?

Comment: Welcome Craig.  This sounds more like something that should be in a comment and not an answer.

Comment: Thanks! I did try to add it as a comment, but the site won't let me post a comment to another user's question or answer without 50 reputation points.